# Android Studio: Cannot resolve method 'getSupportActionBar()'

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I just added ActionBarSherlock to my project using [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/460847), and the project compiled. But I haven't been able to actually use the library. Trying to use `getSupportActionBar()` just yields a `Cannot resolve method` error.

I'm referencing the library at the top of the class. Actually, `import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar` and `import com.actionbarsherlock.*` came up in the suggestions dialog, but I've tried both separately, and both come with the warning `Unused import statement`. So it seems my project doesn't actually know there's a connection between `getSupportActionBar()` and the ActionBarSherlock library. Any ideas on why/how to fix it?

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this in a class that extends SherlockActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet that you extend an Activity and not a SherlockActivity

Also do not forget to use a Sherlock Theme

Comment: Whoops, yeah. I foolishly assumed the import was the problem because it had been such a hassle... thanks.